# unable to setup kong with oidc, konga and keycloak on docker containers

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak, kong-plugin, kong-oidc

Unable to setup kong with oidc , konga and keycloak on docker container in my ubuntu machine.

I tried different docker compose files but it doesnt work for me , can anyone provide a simple docker compose file with kong (with oidc) , konga and keycloak in it and these three should connected to the postgres outside my container

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.